# How can i create a border on custom view with many drawing shapes

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I want to apply the border to this custom view shape 
[image]

which created by many `canvas.draw...()` in `onDraw()`

The border that i want to create and apply to my custom view should have equal range all the way with some distance from the custom view and it should also cover small circle in each slice.

Any idea how to make this?
Thanks.

Comment: @Qadir no it is a custom view draw directly using canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't so much an answer, but more of a recommendation. Take a look at the Porter-Duff modes available to you. Worst case you may need to do some per pixel image manipulation which should be fine as long as the view isn't animated.

On second thought, here's an idea: why not create two images: one large circle which will always draw behind everything and a second which will always draw behind the small circles. The large circle would just be the complete border you want displayed, whereas the small circles would actually only be a semi circle border, which would render on top of the large circle (covering the large circle border under it). The key would then be to rotate the small border circle depending on where it's located. I hippie that makes sense, but it should work and be very efficient too.

Another option would be to separate the rendering into white circles and slightly larger border color circles. If you render the slightly larger (border color) circles first, then render the normal circles (white) on top, then you won't have to worry about any rotations and  it will render correctly if the small outer circles begin to overlap. 
So the idea is similar to the first suggestion. You'll still need a large circle and small circle (both white), but in addition, you'll need slightly larger border colored large and small circles.

I hope this description is a little clearer, but I assume that you are comfortable enough with compound drawables to figure out the rest, given that you've gotten this far in making your view.

All the best implementing it, and feel free to ask for any clarification! :)

Comment: for option 2, is there a problem with the large circle border is not cover by the small circle at the gap between small circle border and small circle itself?

Comment: ok i think that combine option 2 with Porter-Duff will work. Thank you

Comment: I'll try to update this post tomorrow queen I'm not having to type on my phone. There shouldn't be any rendering issues with option 2, but I'll describe later sorry.